# if and else if in calculated field

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a column in SP called Pursuit status that contains various states a proposal can be in. For a diffrent project I need to lump them into 3 buckets (win - loss - pending)

The fields below are:

- Go Pending
- Go – Capture
- No Go
- Bid – Proposal
- No Bid
- Proposal Submitted
- Win
- Loss
- Complete
- Canceled

If I were going to do this in C# it would be something like

```
var cell=""
if( pursuit status = Win)
{
Cell = "Win";
}
else if (pursuit status = "no go" || "No Bid" || "Loss")
{
Cell = "Loss";
}
else
{
Cell = "Pending";
}
```

How would can I achive the same results in a calculated field?

Best I have so far:

```
=IF([Column1]="Win", "Win", "Loss")
```

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint syntax is exactly the same as Excel.

```
=IF( condition1 , IF( condition2, TRUE , FALSE) , IF( condition3, TRUE , FALSE) )
```

So for complex Formulas its possible to create/test in Excel (with named ranges) and paste the Formula to SharePoint

!! SharePoint has the limitation of  **maximum 7 levels** deep nested calls !!

All Functions that work in SharePoint:
https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Hi @Danny ..I have same requirement to convert 12 german month name to digits ..there is limitation only 7 nested if ...do we any other solution?

Comment: Then you have to spread your formula over multiple "columns", just like you would do in Excel IF excel had the same 7 level limitation. Note I left the SharePoint world years ago... I will remove the broken link from this post

Answer (score 0):

You can nest if statements as below

```
=IF(PursuitStatus="Win", "Win", IF(PursuitStatus="Loss", "Loss", "Pending"))
```

In the place of pending you can add remaining if conditions

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me. Thank you so much.

```
=IF([Column1]="Win", "Win", "Loss")
```